# C# Way to sort a list using external criteria

Tags: c#

I'll explain in short what the function is doing/supposed to do:

- Paramter: List of facilities that are needed
- Returns: List of    archetypes that meet over 50% of facilities that
  are required
- An    archetype has X amount of facilities (stored in DB).
- User provides    list of facilities that he wants met (parameter)
- Function looks up    which archetype is most suited for all the
  facilities provided.

  ```
  public List<ArchetypesLokaal> GetArchetypeUitFaciliteiten(List<FaciliteitenLokaalFixed> faciliteiten)
  {
      var archetypes = new List<ArchetypesLokaal>();
      var sortedArchetypes = new List<ArchetypesLokaal>();


      //Iterate over all the archetypes
      foreach(var archetype in db.ArchetypesLokaals)
      {
          //Get all the facilities that are present in archetype
          var temp = GetFaciliteitenVoorArchetype(archetype);

          //Create a new list to add all the facilities that are matched
          var temp2 = new List<FaciliteitenLokaalFixed>();

          //Iterate over the facilities provided as a parameter, these are the facilities that have to be present in the archetype
          foreach(var faciliteit in faciliteiten)
          {
              //CHeck if facility is present in an archetype
              var aanwezig = temp.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Naam.Equals(faciliteit.Naam));
              if (aanwezig!=null)
              {
                  //Add if it's present
                  temp2.Add(faciliteit);
              }
          }
          var needed = faciliteiten.Count;
          var present = temp2.Count;

          //Compare how many facilities were met
          if (present / needed >= .5)
          {
              archetypes.Add(archetype);
          }
      }

     //Todo: sort archetypes by % facilities that were met
      return archetypes;
  }
  ```

So now I'd like to sort my list based on the present/needed, so I can display the best result first. I'm also not sure if what I'm doing is the most efficient way to handle this, but I'm sure my code works as is right now. If you have any suggestions, by all means.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on [.NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)?

Comment: you need it sorted based on `present`, right? and why don't you use english identifier names in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to sort your output based on `present = temp2.Count` local variable. You could wrap your result in some container, for example a [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var archetypes = new List<Tuple<int, ArchetypesLokaal>>();

//Iterate over all the archetypes
foreach(var archetype in db.ArchetypesLokaals)
{
    //Get all the facilities that are present in archetype
    var temp = GetFaciliteitenVoorArchetype(archetype);

    //Create a new list to add all the facilities that are matched
    var temp2 = new List<FaciliteitenLokaalFixed>();

    //Iterate over the facilities provided as a parameter, these are the facilities that have to be present in the archetype
    foreach(var faciliteit in faciliteiten)
    {
        //CHeck if facility is present in an archetype
        var aanwezig = temp.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Naam.Equals(faciliteit.Naam));
        if (aanwezig!=null)
        {
            //Add if it's present
            temp2.Add(faciliteit);
        }
    }
    var needed = faciliteiten.Count;
    var present = temp2.Count;

    //Compare how many facilities were met
    if (present / needed >= .5)
    {
        archetypes.Add(new Tuple<int, ArchetypesLokaal>(present, archetype));
    }
}

return archetypes.OrderByDescending(q => q.Item1).Select(q => q.Item2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

So it's not a complete solution but assuming you have a nested object of Facilteits within the Archetype

```
 var matchedArchetypes = archetypes
            .Select(x => new { arch = x, cnt = x.Faciliteits.Join(faciliteitNaams, a => a.Naam, b => b.Naam, (a, b) => a).Count() })
            .ToList();
```

Will give you the Archetype and the count of matched facilities

Answer (score 1):

As others stated: I'd map this into a list of archetype/counts first and then stuff that into the lists you require (and sort based on this information). Something like this:

```
 var archetypeUitFaciliteiten = db.ArchetypesLokaals.Select(archetypeLokaal => { 
    var faciliteitenVoorArchetype = GetFaciliteitenVoorArchetype(archetypeLokaal);
    return new {
        ArcheType = archetypeLokaal,
        Present = faciliteiten.Count(f => faciliteitenVoorArchetype.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Naam.Equals(f.Naam)) != null),
        Needed = faciliteiten.Count
    };
});
```

Now you can either map (`Select`) this into a list, based on the Present/Needed ratio as in your example, or sort (`OrderBy`) this list based on these properties.

(Sorry if I butchered the language - I don't speak dutch)

Comment: Hey thanks! Kind of alot shorter than what I had. Also, you didn't :)